# IF function does not return value

Tags: excel, if-statement

My problem: in Sheet1 Cell A5 formula:

```
=((A1-A2)+(A3-A4))/2
```

In Sheet2 Cell A1 an IF function:

```
=IF('Sheet1'!A5=1;"Good";0)
```

Excel only returns the **"value if false".**

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

Where´s the thing:

I´ve tried with different cells and it works just fine
it only fails with this specific cell

What might be the problem?

Problem Solved =IF('Sheet1'!A5<>1;"Good";0)

The equal element does not work alone.

Comment: Try `=IF('Sheet1'!A5=1; "Good"; 0)`.

Comment: There are no semicolons in Excel's IF.

Comment: @rbm - There are if the computer's list separator is set for semi-colons (as is the case in several European countries).

Comment: @Jeeped - did not know that! thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel - find a value and copy into different sheets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035694/excel-find-a-value-and-copy-into-different-sheets)

Comment: Now that you've added the missing tick (e.g. `'`, you might try rounding the returned value to avoid [15 digit precision floating point errors](http://blogs.office.com/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/). `=ROUND(((A1-A2)+(A3-A4))/2, 6)` rounds to a 6 decimal precision.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify A5's formula to `=(A1-A2+A3-A4)/2`. Sheet2's formula will be `=IF(Sheet1!A5=1, "Good", "0")`

I was not aware that some Locales use `;` in `IF` as a separator. Today I learned. If you are in such Locale, use `=IF(Sheet1!A5=1; "Good"; "0")`. I tested this on Excel 2013 and it works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try following in A1 of sheet2 :

```
=IF(Sheet1!E1=1,"Good",0)
```

You will get value 0. And if you use following

```
=IF(Sheet1!E1=5,"Good",0)
```

you will get value "Good" provided sheet1:A5 has a value of 5 after computation.